# Microservices security with FastAPI

Tags: python, security, microservices, fastapi

I'm working on a personal project which makes use of Python, FastAPI and a microservices architecture.

I want to learn more about security so I'm trying to add some into this. I have read through the [fastapi security intro](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/security/) and it mostly makes sense to me.

One thing I'm not sure about though is going about handling this cleanly in a microservices architecture.

Let's assume I have 2 services, `user` service and `bankAccount` service. The `user` service is supposed to handle everything with regards to a new user registering on my site, to logging them in, etc. At this point, it shouldn't be too difficult to authenticate the user as the `user` service can access it's db.

The part where I'm not sure about the best way to go forward would be with the `bankAccount` service. If a user makes a request to an endpoint within that service, how should I go about authenticating/authorising them?

The two options I can think of are as follows:

1. Create an `/authenticate` endpoint which has the sole purpose of other services being able to call it. Then, create a wrapper function in `bankAccount` service which wraps every endpoint and calls the `/authenticate` endpoint before running it's function
2. Create an `/authenticate` endpoint which has the sole purpose of other services being able to call it. Then, using something like NGINX or some sort of gateway, have this called before sending the request to the `bankAccount` service.

I lack experience/knowledge in this area so I'm not sure which of these would be the better option. I am leaning towards 2 so that I don't have to copy the wrapper code from the `bankAccount` service to any new service I create, but I don't know anything about NGINX or other gateways so any advice on how best to proceed here would be appreciated.

Comment: Security in Microservices is more a topic for a book (or a series of books) than a Stack Overflow question. If you have a specific question on a single point please ask. But please understand that be can not cover such a broad topic here.

Comment: That's a fair point. In that case, are there any books you would recommend?

As far as this question goes then, which of the 2 options above would you recommend going forward? Some sort of gateway to handle authentication or have each microservice authenticate the call?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert in the subject, since I started recently diving into the microservices topic. So, take what I'm saying with a pinch of salt.

**JWT AUTH WITH PUBLIC AND PRIVATE KEY**

One thing you could do, is to use `JWT` authentication in all of your microservices. Basically, every service is capable of decrypting/reading the `JWT` token, handle the necessary verifications and respond accordingly.

The authentication service would be the one in charge of generating the tokens, so the idea is to use asymmetric encryption, where one key, owned by the authentication service, is used to generate the tokens, while other (public) keys are used to assess the authenticity of the token provided by users. The public/private keys could also be a pair of public/private certificates.

This is no way a scalable approach, as all the public keys have to be updated in case of an update of the key. Also, if the content of the `token` or the checks that are to be performed on the key change, then all the microservices have to be updated accordingly, which can be a tedious and long process.

Unfortunately, I haven't got any occasion to dive deeper as the topic is not simple and experimenting approaches in production isn't a good idea.

If someone more experienced than me can fill in missing details or other approaches, feel free to edit this answer or to comment below and I'll try to learn and update my answer.

Comment: This seems like an interesting approach. I imagine if I'm using a public key, I could simply create a secret in K8s with the public key in it and have my microservices access that? That way, I only need to update the secret with any new public keys instead of in every service?

Comment: Technically, you create the public and the private keys at the same time. You can see it as an SSL certificate for your auth service. You can sure update the public/private keys, but you'll need to stop the services and synchronize them all to use the same key. Also, the services have to accept the same payload for the JWT token.